# Retrieve multiple data in recycler view using FirebaseRecyclerOptions

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-realtime-database

I am using `FirebaseRecyclerOptions` in calling the database, however, I cannot get all of the data in the database. Here is the structure of the database: [database structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hNfjc.png) the yellow underline is the user id (UID) and below is another node that contains the data that I want to retrieve in the RecyclerView.

Here is a snippet of the code

```
    FirebaseRecyclerOptions<RegisterParking> options =
            new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<RegisterParking>()
                    .setQuery(FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("RegParkingArea"), RegisterParking.class)
                    .build();

    voPListAdapter = new VoPListAdapter(options);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(voPListAdapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you're passing the following two arguments to the setQuery() method:

```
.setQuery(FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("RegParkingArea"), RegisterParking.class)
```

It means that the adapter expects to render on the screen `RegisterParking` objects. If you take a closer look at your database schema, under the `RegParkingArea` node, you can find UIDs and **not** `RegisterParking` objects. The objects that you want to display in the RecycerView exist under each UID. So when reading the data from the database, the Firebase-UI library tries to map each child under the above reference into an object of type `RegisterParking`, which is actually not possible since the UIDs are strings.

So if you're allowed to change the database schema, then you should either denormalize the data, basically copying the data under another node, or change the actual data into:

```
db-root
 |
 --- RegParkingArea
       |
       --- $pushedId
             |
             --- uid: "4u9h...XrP2"
             |
             --- //other fields.
```

What I have basically done, I have removed a level from the database tree. If you'll use this schema, then you can leave the code as it is and everything will work perfectly fine.

One more thing to note is that if you need to get all parking of a particular user, then you can use the following query:

```
DatabaseReference db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
Query queryByUid = db.child("RegParkingArea").orderByChild("uid").equalTo(uid);
```

Comment: Hey there. Can I help you with other information?